# R Programming. Code not working. Why?

Tags: r, csv

I have a folder containing 10 files namely 01.csv,02.csv .... 10.csv

I have to take a string of numbers from the user but only open the files corresponding to it.
Note: The user may also enter numbers not in range of 1-10 in which case we have to return a line saying error

Here's part of my code: I have saved the number from user in z. Now,

```
for(i in seq_along(z)){ 

  if(z[i]>0 & z[i]<10){

    z[i] <- paste("0", z[i], sep="")
    z[i] <- paste(z[i], "csv", sep=".")
    a<-read.csv(z[i])
    print(a)
  }
}
```

The code runs fine when I input z as single digit no like 1,2,3 etc
But when I enter z as a string of numbers like 1:4 etc, it only reads the first number i.e.1 in this case.

Why? What should I do to overcome this?

Answer (score 2):

If `z` is a string, such as "1:4", you can obtain the corresponding vector as follows

```
z <- "1:4"
z <- eval(parse(text = z))
z
# [1] 1 2 3 4
```

Answer (score 0):

May be this helps

```
fun1 <- function(z){
  a <- vector('list', length(z))
  z1 <- sprintf('%02d%s', z, '.csv')
  for(i in seq_along(z)){
     stopifnot(z[i] > 0 & z [i] < 10)
     a[[i]]<-read.csv(z1[i], sep='')
     print(a[[i]])
  }
  #a
 }

 z <- 11:12
 fun1(z)
 #Error: z[i] > 0 & z[i] < 10 is not TRUE

 z <- c(1,11)
 fun1(z)
 #  Col1 Col2
 #1    3    4
 #2    4    8
 #Error: z[i] > 0 & z[i] < 10 is not TRUE

  z <- 1:2
  fun1(z)
  #  Col1 Col2
  #1    3    4
  #2    4    8
  #  Col1 Col2
  #1    3    5
  #2    4    9
```